# Determine element of url from webview shouldOverRideUrlLoading

Tags: android, webview

I am displaying a html in a custom activity with a webview. I am overriding

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
```

to intercept certain urls. Now I would like to be able to figure out some more details about the html around that url.

In my case I would like to get the html element that contains the url. E.g. if the url comes from

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/136445/manfred-moser">Manfred Moser</a>
```

I would like to be able to somehow retrieve the value "Manfred Moser" from within the anchor tag. Is there a way to do that. I found that you do not have access to the DOM from Java.

One way I can think of would be to download the page separately and parse it all before even loading it in webview. However that is an ugly hack at best. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dirty hack:

1. Bind some Java object so that it can be called from Javascript with WebView:

   ```
   addJavascriptInterface(javaObjectExposed, "JSname")
   ```
2. Force execute javascript within an existing page by

   ```
   WebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.JSname.passData("some data");");
   ```

Described here: http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/

Note: this is a security risk - any JS code in this web page could access/call your binded Java object. Best to pass some one-time cookies to loadUrl() and pass them back your Java object to check that it's your code making the call.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to get that going next week.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Peter Knego's approach, there is the inverse:

1. Use `addJavascriptInterface()`, per his step #1
2. For your link, use an `onClick` attribute on your `<a>` tag to call out some method on the Java object from step #1, where the Java object turns around and loads the URL into the `WebView`, and supplies whatever sort of identifying information you want.

Suffice it to say, there's no way to get the information you want from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

Comment: I do not control the webpage that gets loaded at all. So would that somehow still work?

Comment: @Manfred Moser: No, sorry, mine won't work in that case. Mr. Knego's approach may work, if you can figure out a "bookmarklet" style snippet of Javascript that can get your data, but it'll be tricky.