# Getting raw HTML / adding Javascript to WebView pages

Tags: java, android

I have a mobile flow for registration that I want to use in my app,  and I do not have control of the source -- 
I am looking for a way to grab a few pieces of data when the user finishes registering, (confirmation number, etc.) that will be sent to my app (hopefully via Android's `addJavascriptInterface`)

I am certain on one thing - the `id` of the element I need. The flow could change, and is already a few pages long, So I'm looking for a general solution. The basic Idea I'm hoping for is this:

Inject a JavaScript snippet to each page during `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, which will automatically call my `JavaScript Interface` and check for the value of the field with the `id` I'm looking for. (or just return the entire HTML, and I'll do it in Java)

```
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
             @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                 //inject javascript here to get value
                 return false;
            }});
```

I've seen tutorials on using `addJavascriptInterface`, but they all seem to assume some control or understanding of the 'single' page that will be navigated to. Since I have a potentially lengthy flow (3+ pages) and no control over the source, I am interested in hearing any suggestions.

Comment: So how dom you know when user is done with the "flow"?

Comment: @PeterKnego Tenatively, the url will have 'confirmation' in it, and an element with this a certain `id` will exist.. Little loose, I know :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check URL of the current page and if it's the right one insert JavaScript in the curent page. With the help of Java-JS binding you could get some data out. See my previous answer: [Determine element of url from webview shouldOverRideUrlLoading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124064/determine-element-of-url-from-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading/5124119#5124119)